# Campo do tipo GEOMETRY no Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, migrations, sequelize-js

Olá, queria criar uma tabela usando as migrations com sequelize, e criar um campo de position do tipo GEOMETRY. O banco que estou utilizando é o postgres.

Tentei esse código:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('users', { 
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      position: {
        type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY,
      },
    });
  },

  down: queryInterface => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  }
};
```

Da um erro falando que type "geometry" não existe.

Como eu faço pra setar um campo desse tipo??

Comment: Voce ativou a extensao `postgis` no seu banco?

Comment: Não lembro, mas acho que não. Como faço isso?

Comment: pela linha de comando acho que e assim: `psql -U [superuser] [sua database] CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`. Nao tenho certeza, mas tente fazer o teste. Se nao, faca uma pesquisa de como ativar essa extensao, para o postgres reconhecer esse tipo multidimensional de dado.

Comment: vou tentar, assim que tiver resultado retorno

Comment: está habilitado, mas continua dando erro que está em cima

Answer (score 0):

entao, pelo que eu vi no codigo fonte, coloque no seu `type` o seguinte:

```js
Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POINT') // letras em caixa alta.
```

Isto vai indicar uma geometria de 2 dimensoes.
Lembrando que como a [documentacao do sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/data-types.js~GEOMETRY.html) mostra, voce pode escolher 3 tipos: `Point`, `LineString` e `Polygon`.

Quando voce for criar um novo registro no banco, deve informar o `type` na hora de criar. Exemplo:

```js
const point = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [39.807222,-76.984722]}; // especifica o type para `Point`.

User.create({username: 'username', position: point });
```

Acho que e isso. Espero ter ajudado.